# Cant cast monobehaviour base class

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a baseclass that inherits from Monobehaviour. How do i cast my monobehaviour to the base class when finding it in the hierarchy?

```cs
GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public MonoBaseClass MyThing;

    void Awake() {
        MyThing = GameObject.Find("Child") as MonoBaseClass;
    }
}

MonoBaseClass : MonoBehaviour  {

    public void BaseClassMethod() {}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameObject.Find returns a GameObject, a MonoBehaviour is a component of a GameObject. That's why you can't cast the GameObject to the MonoBaseClass.

Instead you have to get a reference of the GameObject and then get the Component:

```
GameObject childGameObject = GameObject.Find("Child");
MyThing = childGameObject.GetComponent<MonoBaseClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FindObjectOfType<MonoBaseClass>()`, i.e.:

```cs
void Awake() {
    MyThing = FindObjectOfType<MonoBaseClass>();
}
```

Comment: OMG! Is this new? :o

Comment: I dont see how i can do that on MyThing since you will be calling FindObjectOfType on itself and not on MyThing.

Comment: `MonoBaseClass` is a `type` and a Unity `Component`. I guess that the `MonoBaseClass` script is attached to a game object, that's all you need for `FindObjectOfType<T>` to work (unless there're multiple components of type `T`, in that case you have to choose the specific component with other conditions, or get all those components, if you need all of them, with `FindObjectsOfType<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Problem with both `Find` and `FindObjectOfType` is: They are quite slow and you will get the first hit from the entire scene.

If the Component you are looking for is on a Gameobject which is a child of the current GameObject (which seems the case) than you can just use:

```
MyThing = GetComponentInChildren<MonoBaseClass>();
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html

Of course this will anyway still only get the first hit. For more use an array and `GetComponentsInChildren<T>()`